# c# filter function with sql and parameters

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net, substring

I've used code I've previously done in VB two years back, converted almost all of it to work in c# environment though I've hit a brick wall with the last part as i'm not sure how to approach it.

Previous VB code

```
If Not binGotOne Then
strSQL = Mid$(strSQL, 1, InStr(strSQL, "WHERE") - 1)
End If
```

Current C# code

```
            /* This section I belive is substrings though I'm not sure,
             currently I can't get it to work as I'm not sure how to apporach it*/
            if (!filter)
            {
                query = (query, 1,(query, "WHERE") - 1);
            }
```

The c# section is last part of full function shown below which I can't seem to get my head around.

```
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
        Security security = new Security();

        try
        {
            connection.ConnectionString = connectionPath;
            connection.Open();

            Boolean filter = false;
            string query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM Staff WHERE ");

            if (txtstaffid.Text != null)
            {
                filter = true;
                query = query + "Staff_StaffId = " + txtstaffid.Text + "'";
            }
            else if (cbotitle.Text != null)
            {
                filter = true;
                query = query + "Staff_Title = '" + cbotitle.Text + "";
            }
            else if (cborole.Text != null)
            {
                filter = true;
                query = query + "Staff_Role = '" + cborole.Text + "'";
            }
            else if (txtfname.Text != null)
            {
                filter = true;
                query = query + "Staff_Firstname = '" + txtfname.Text + "'";
            }
            else if (txtsname.Text != null)
            {
                filter = true;
                query = query + "Staff_Surname = '" + txtsname.Text + "'";
            }
            else if (txtpostcode.Text != null)
            {
                filter = true;
                query = query + "Staff_Postcode = '" + txtpostcode.Text + "'";
            }
            else if (txtemail.Text != null)
            {
                filter = true;
                query = query + "Staff_Email = '" + txtemail.Text + "'";
            }

            /* This section I belive is substrings though I'm not sure,
             currently I can't get it to work as I'm not sure how to apporach it*/
            if (!filter)
            {
                query = (query, 1, (query, "WHERE") - 1);
            }

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
            SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            dap.Fill(ds);
            BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
            bs.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            dgv.DataSource = bs;
            dap.Update(ds);
        }
        catch (SqlException sql)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(sql.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
            connection.Dispose();
        }
```

Comment: My StaffId is `1 OR 1=1 --`... read about SQL injection and about data access in general. Manually crafting SQL strings is considered harmful and outdated.

Comment: I was aware the last section was a bit out-date, I do intend on changing it, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the job of that part of the code is to remove " WHERE" from the SQL if there was no filter added to it. A literal translation to c# would be..

`sql = sql.Substring(0, sql.IndexOf("WHERE") - 1);`

Perhaps this would be a bit clearer

`sql = sql.Replace(" WHERE", String.Empty);`

Also, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection - you should use parameters.

Comment: parameters for last section or whole thing? I mean currently I have have it so the full query goes into sqlcommand which I thought prevented sql injection.

Comment: @10gez10 it only protects agains injection and uses escaping when you use parameters for all input. If you don't type a number for `StaffId` it will create an invalid SQL string.

Comment: I understand now, thanks all for your help I will have to re-write this completely.

Answer (score 1):

I would aproach querying using system.Linq.

You can the do:

```
DataSet.Select(record => record.column == requiredvalue);
```

That would return an IQueryable on which you can apply more conditions.
The query is only executed when you start using the result.

For example:

```
var result = DataSet.Select(...);
List list = result.ToList();
```

The execution of the query occurs on ToList();